# SQL Join Condition with CASE

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which I am using to join on a number of columns to a single column however I am getting 'Incorrect Syntax near Academic Year'. Any thoughts - I am not too sure how to end the case within the join

```
select distinct 
    bb.pk1 as 'LearnSourceKey',
    sc.pk1 as 'SISSourceKey',
    row_number () over (partition by bb.pk1 order by sc.SISCourseKey) as 'RowRank'
from
    Source.SISCourse sc
    left join source.SISTerm st on sc.TermSourceKey=st.SISTermKey
    inner join Source.COURSE_MAIN bb
        on bb.batch_uid = substring(CatalogNumber, 1, (len(CatalogNumber) - 1)) + 
            case 
                when st.TermDescription='Semester 1' 
                then 'SEM-1'  + '_' + st.AcademicYear
```

Comment: you did not `end` the `case` expression.

Comment: You should provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1):

This is your query, basically:

```
select distinct bb.pk1 as LearnSourceKey,
       sc.pk1 as SISSourceKey,
       row_number () over (partition by bb.pk1 order by sc.SISCourseKey) as RowRank
from Source.SISCourse sc left join
     source.SISTerm st
     on sc.TermSourceKey = st.SISTermKey inner join
     Source.COURSE_MAIN bb
     on bb.batch_uid = (left(CatalogNumber, len(CatalogNumber) - 1) + 
                        (case when st.TermDescription = 'Semester 1' then 'SEM-1'  + '_' + st.AcademicYear end) 
                       );
```

Your `case` has no `else` clause.  Hence, anything that doesn't meet the `when` condition will be `NULL`.  This means that you can simplify it to:

```
select distinct bb.pk1 as LearnSourceKey,
       sc.pk1 as SISSourceKey,
       row_number () over (partition by bb.pk1 order by sc.SISCourseKey) as RowRank
from Source.SISCourse sc left join
     source.SISTerm st
     on sc.TermSourceKey = st.SISTermKey inner join
     Source.COURSE_MAIN bb
     on st.TermDescription = 'Semester 1' and
        bb.batch_uid = (left(CatalogNumber, len(CatalogNumber) - 1) + 
                        st.AcademicYear
                       );
```

This (as with your original query) assumes `st.AcademicYear` is a string.

Answer (score 0):

Case statement should have end expression

```
select distinct 
    bb.pk1 as 'LearnSourceKey',
    sc.pk1 as 'SISSourceKey',
    row_number () over (partition by bb.pk1 order by sc.SISCourseKey) as 'RowRank'
from
Source.SISCourse sc
left join source.SISTerm st on sc.TermSourceKey=st.SISTermKey
inner join Source.COURSE_MAIN bb 
      on bb.batch_uid = substring(CatalogNumber,  1, (len(CatalogNumber) - 1)) + 
         case 
            when st.TermDescription='Semester 1' 
            then  'SEM-1'  + '_' + st.AcademicYear 
         end
```